# How to make a Potion Spawner in 1.12.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map but there's a problem, how to make a Potion Spawner in Minecraft 1.12.2?

I am trying to make a command :

```
/setblock ~0 ~1 ~0 mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{CustomPotionEffect:"Jump_boost",Amplifier:1,Second:10,id:Potion},SpawnCount:5,SpawnRange:3,maxNearbyEntities:3,Delay:15s,MinSpawnDelay:15s,MaxSpawnDelay:15s}
```

It works but the spawner doesn't spawn anything. If you know how to do this, please tell me how to type that command.

Comment: Try to reduce the command until it works, then add details back in.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure spawners can't spawn non-mobs.

Comment: @Zelo101 (they can)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help you

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnCount:1,SpawnRange:5,RequiredPlayerRange:5,MaxNearbyEntities:25,Delay:50,MinSpawnDelay:25,MaxSpawnDelay:50,SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:Item",Item:{id:bone,Count:10}}}
```

This command will spawn a mobspawner that spawns bone. The website that i used was [THIS](https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/#!30176) one

Comment: I had an idea that you could do so a mob spawns with the item and then dies immediately

Answer (score -2):

I used this website: https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/#!30176

This is the command I found:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnCount:1,SpawnRange:5,RequiredPlayerRange:5,MaxNearbyEntities:25,Delay:50,MinSpawnDelay:25,MaxSpawnDelay:50,SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:Item",Item:{id:bone,Count:10}}}
```

Comment: This appears to be a: a duplicate answer over a year later than the identical 1, and b: summon bones, not potions.